# What is the Controller entry in the performance tab of Symfony's web profiler?

Tags: php, profiling, response, symfony

Apologies for the vague question but can anyone who has seen this before please  identify what the "controller" entry means?

I am trying to track down this long page reload.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good question - how would you feel about a significant retitle though: *What is the Controller entry in the performance tab of Symfony's web profiler?* or something. Does that deviate too far from your intentions?

Comment: What is the content of this controller?

Comment: The problem is I don't know which controller, stepping through it's between redirects it dispatched the kernel.response then hangs.

Does the profiler have the content available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to be a bit of a red herring. It was actually the a custom Redis session save handler related to [this issue](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/issues/250).

Comment: How did you figure out it's Redis? I don't have it but I have same problem